# StringCopy function: simple issue

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, post-increment

I have this function that gets two pointers to strings.

```
void copy(char *s, char *t){    /*copy the string pointed by t into string pointed by s*/

    while( (*s = *t) != '\0'){
        s++;
        t++;
    }
    return;
}
```

The problem is: i see it works, both with `s++` and `t++` (that means "pointers, go to next character and check it") and with `*s++` and `*t++`. So i'm asking this shouldn't `*s++` be modifying the character pointed by the pointer? Why it works the same?

Compiled in ubuntu with some sample strings.
Thanks in advance

Comment: guess what would work too? `while (*s++ = *t++);`

Comment: Btw, your parameters are named oddly, because the first word pair that comes to my mind from `s` and `t` is **source** and **target**.

Comment: *"shouldn't `*s++` be modifying the character pointed by the pointer?"* -- The statement that modifies the character pointed to is `(*s)++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts.

**Firstly**:

> *both with s++ and t++ (that means "pointers, go to next character and check it") and with *s++ and *t++.*

Well, the outcome you see is same, that does not mean they are same.

In case of snippets like

```
    s++;
    t++;
```

and

```
    *s++;
    *t++;
```

they yield same behaviour, as in both the cases, only the side-effect of post-increment matters (as they are *persistent*, affect the actual variable), not the produced result (the result of applying the dereference operator is discarded).

Actually, if you try to compile the second version (`*s++;` thingy), you will get a warning like

> Warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

Then, **secondly**:

> *shouldn't `*s++` be modifying the character pointed by the pointer*

No, read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The post increment binds higher than that of the dereference operator, the side effect kicks in after the  value computation of the result, which is the dereference operation.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is better to declare the second parameter with qualifier `const`.

```
void copy(char *s, const char *t);
```

It is a contract between the function and the user of the function that the function guarantees that the source string that is copied will not be changed.

And it would be even more better to declare the function like

```
char * copy(char *s, const char *t);
```

when the function returns pointer to the first character of the resulted string.

As for the original question then if you write the function like

```
void copy(char *s, char *t){    /*copy the string pointed by t into string pointed by s*/

    while( (*s = *t) != '\0'){
        *s++;
        *t++;
    }
    // return;
}
```

then the values of the expressions `*s++` and `*t++` are not used. So in this context the dereferencing of the pointers is redundant operation.

However you could write the function the following way where the dereferencing makes sense

```
void copy(char *s, char *t){    /*copy the string pointed by t into string pointed by s*/

    while( ( *s++ = *t++) != '\0');
    // return;
}
```

Comment: And I could as well remove the `!= '\0'`, am I right?

Comment: @MarkiplierB Yes, you are write. You could just write while( ( *s++ = *t++ ) );